# npm install error (code EBADPLATFORM)

Tags: node.js, npm

When I tried to run `npm install`, it gave me this error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aroma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03- 
25T11_33_58_338Z-debug.log
```

The node version:

```
$node -v
v8.10.0
```

I tried every thing, like:

```
npm cache clear 
npm cache verify
npm i -g npm@latest
```

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Nodejs again but still get the same error.

Answer (score 60):

I had the same issue, deleting my "package-lock.json" and re-running `npm install` worked

For those having issue on **render.com**

- remove `package-lock.json` from your repo or add to `gitignore`
- then run the build command `npm install ; npm run build` using the build from last comment option on `render.com dashboard`

Comment: Very helpful. I had broken `package-lock.json` file in my home directory that was breaking installs *only* there.

Answer (score 26):

Error is indicating that you are installing `fsevents` module in other OS rather than Mac

`fsevents`  module only works for Mac Operting system

Comment: thank you yes I'm on windows machine  I removed the {fsevents } from the package.json  and it's work

Comment: I don't even have fsevents in my package.json but still getting the same error. How to fix this issue. Please let me know

Answer (score 13):

This worked effortless for me on Windows:

1. Go to project's "package-lock.json" file.
2. Press "Ctrl+F" (to enable keyword search).
3. Type "darwin".
4. Wherever it says "darwin" in the file, change that to "win32".

Restart your VS Code and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!  

For Linux, change it to 'Linux from 'darwin'

Comment: Thanks! Just removed `"os": [ "darwin" ],` at all

Comment: not working on windows 10

Comment: But what if I DON'T have a project? What if I just want to install npm's tool "n" on my system globally?

Answer (score 8):

Add following to your project's package.json

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
 },
```

and then install with --no-optional

Comment: Thank you, this worked, even without running --no-optional flag

Answer (score 5):

Same npm install error (code EBADPLATFORM):

I had forced fsevents onto my windows machine npm i -f fsevents...
**npm responded "I hope you know what your doing".**

To repair, needed to

1. delete package-lock.json
2. delete line: fsevents@2.3.2 in package.json (your suffix may differ)
3. re-ran npm install

Answer (score 3):

Remove `"fsevents": "version"`, on `package.json` if you try to install on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing on Mac. I deleted `"os": [ "darwin" ]` from `package.lock.json`, ran the build, deployed to my Google Cloud App Engine project, and it finally worked.

Source: [belykh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035099/belykh)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475492/npm-install-error-code-ebadplatform/72377102#comment119146054_66397384) (Nothing posted in any of the other answers helped me.)

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all:

```
  Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: 
  wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
  (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

This module doesn't support Windows, you can't use it if you're on Windows.

Comment: I have the same issue. My problem is this app should targer android AND ios. I had this project running in windows, then i cloned it in a Mac (and works) but not it no longer runs on windows. How do I keep both repos working at the same time? I understand package.json is a source controlled item

Answer (score 1):

I think In your Project Folder First Delete package.lock.json and then try:

```
npm install
```

This is Works For Me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my dev machine (Win 10 x64). I had no intention of running or using fsevents locally. I just needed to upgrade my local copy of fsevents, to resolve a vulnerability.  Running with the `-f` option solved it:

```
npm install fsevents@1.2.9 -f
```

Note: `-f` means "force installation". npm gives an ominous warning like "I hope you know what you're doing". Afaik fsevents isn't dangerous to have on a win32 machine. It only "works" on mac. The npm page for fsevents says "This is a low-level library. For a cross-platform file watching module that uses fsevents, check out Chokidar". I was only upgrading and wasn't choosing to use it on a win32 machine. So keep that in-mind.

That being-said, it didn't break anything for me. No BSoDs, errors, etc.  App still works. Build works. All good.

Answer (score 0):

This error message says that **fsevents** package does not support your operating system. In my case the solution for this error was to upgrade **npm** to the latest version.

Answer (score -2):

please first delete package-lock.json file and remove "win-node-env": "^0.4.0" this line from package.json[image]

Comment: where is package-lock.json located? And Package.json does not have "win-node-env": "^0.4.0"

Comment: if you had installed npm then you have the package-lock.json file otherwise you don't have and it's located in the root directory

Answer (score -3):

Add peer dependency in your JSON package like below

```
{
  "name": "chai-as-promised",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "chai": "1.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what worked for me:

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. run `npm i`