# Why am I getting a EBADPLATFORM err when installing node

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am trying to update my project node version because I needed to update some packages that depended on a newer version of typescript.

I updated npm and then ran **npm cache clean -f**. Then when trying to run:

```
npm i -g n
```

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@6.0.1: wanted  {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-18T08_58_12_545Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  ...
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
  "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
  "@angular/cli": "^8.3.4",
  "@angular/common": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.6",
  "@angular/core": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/http": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.8",
  "@angular/router": "^6.1.8",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.2",
  "@material-extended/mde": "^2.3.1",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
  "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
  "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.2",
  "@types/chart.js": "^2.8.5",
  "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.1",
  "amazing-time-picker": "^1.8.0",
  "angular-popper": "^1.0.0",
  "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
  "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
  "angular2-wizard": "^0.4.0",
  "angular4-datepicker": "^1.0.1",
  "angular5-csv": "0.2.11",
  "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
  "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
  "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
  "core-js": "^2.6.9",
  "d3": "^4.13.0",
  "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
  "jquery": "^3.4.1",
  "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
  "jspdf-autotable": "^3.1.1",
  "localforage": "^1.7.3",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11",
  "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
  "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
  "ng2-archwizard": "^2.1.0",
  "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
  "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
  "ng2-date-picker": "^2.11.0",
  "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
  "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.4",
  "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
  "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
  "ng4-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.0",
  "ngforage": "^3.0.1",
  "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
  "ngx-chips": "1.9.8",
  "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.3",
  "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
  "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.4",
  "ngx-stepper": "^1.1.6",
  "ngx-toastr": "^10.2.0",
  "npm": "^5.10.0",
  "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
  "rxjs": "6.3.3",
  "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
  "typescript": "^3.6.3",
  "xlsx": "^0.13.5",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.3",
  "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.8.4",
  "@types/node": "^10.14.18",
  "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.3",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
  "karma": "~1.4.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.0",
  "replace-in-file": "^3.4.4",
  "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
  "tslint": "~4.5.0",
  "webpack": "^4.40.2"
}
}
```

The reason for updating was because  the **getColorDepth()** function was undefined after updating **typescript** to @3.6.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install error (code EBADPLATFORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475492/npm-install-error-code-ebadplatform)

Comment: Not a duplicate error - that error is at fsevents@1.1.3...  My error is at n@6.0.1..

Comment: The package name is irrelevant. The error is the same: your OS (Windows) is not supported by the package.

Comment: OK cool @KonradRudolph but how do I remove the package that is not supported by my OS?

Comment: There’s nothing to remove, it’s not installed. Your command `npm i -g n` is *attempting to install it*.

Comment: Aah OK i get it.. So I have to update Node through the Windows installer.. Thank you @KonradRudolph your a legend!