# npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM when i push project to deploy a GitHub branch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

Below error occurs when I push the project to deploy a GitHub branch:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.SSqKk/_logs/2021-05-22T14_25_47_923Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
**npm ERR! contactKeepar@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`**
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contactKeepar@1.0.0 Heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.SSqKk/_logs/2021-05-22T14_25_47_980Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

*****heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`*****
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49475492/2873538

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install error (code EBADPLATFORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475492/npm-install-error-code-ebadplatform)

Answer (score 0):

1. delete package-lock.json (and node_modules)
2. npm install
3. push new package-lock.json to GitHub

and it should work

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127283/555139 for an explanation of why you should not delete package-lock.json.